# Cakephp 2.4.5 - Using Count with Sum in query

Tags: php, cakephp, count

I haven't really seen any cakephp examples of getting a Count value as a field in the query results.
Here is what I did

```
    $searchfilter = array(
                        'Booking.bookingdate >=' => $date_period_current_start,
                        'Booking.bookingdate <=' => $date_period_current_end,
                        'Booking.merchant_id =' => $this->Session->read('Auth.ActiveMerchant')
                    );
    $fields       = array(
                    'COUNT(*) as reccount',
                    'SUM(Booking.pax) as totalpax',
                    );


    $bookings_period_current = $this->Booking->find('all', array('conditions' => $searchfilter, 'fields' => $fields)

    var_dump($bookings_period_current);
```

Now this seems to have worked fine, my var_dump produces:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'reccount' => string '7' (length=1)
          'totalpax' => string '28' (length=2)
```

I guess my questions are:

1) Is this the right way of doing a Count with cakephp? Note I'm not using the normal find('Count',...) method

2) in my $fields variable I specified COUNT(*) as reccount... Is this very inefficient? The Bookings table has several other fields but all i really want is the total number of records, and the sum of Booking.pax.

Cheers
Kevin

Comment: As far i know, Yes this is the right way.... The formatting may look odd but you can use `afterFind()` on you model to reformat your result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right way for `COUNT(*)` is `find('count')`, but if You want to get more fields in the same query Your solution is ok.

You can also use:

a) [Virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html)

```
$this->Booking->virtualFields = array(
  'reccount' => 'COUNT(*)',
  'totalpax' => 'SUM(Booking.pax)'
); // or put it in Booking model
$this->Booking->find('all', array('fields' => array('reccount', 'totalpax')));
```

b) `$this->Booking->query();`